# Lost packets sent from android phone to laptop

Tags: android

I have an Android program sends strings to Laptop pc via Wifi hotspot on Laptop, created by netsh command. When I run the same program from another laptop and send a lot of strings, target laptop receives all of them, but when I send it from my phone, some strings were lost, when I send it fast (20ms/PKG) by pressing the button in smart phone to send strings. Does the phone's wifi perform worse than laptop? Or is there any other error? (I must use TCP protocol to send packages).